# How does this Go code set the value of an object through a pointer, without dereferencing?

Tags: pointers, go

I'm learning Go from a Java/Python background, and am confused by this code from the Go tutorial. In the following code, the line

```
p.X = 1e9
```

sets the value of v.X to 1e9 using pointer p. **As p is merely a pointer to v, isn't dereferencing necessary to set v's value?** Thus the correct statement would be:

```
*p.X = 1e9
```

Naturally, this results in an error. Can someone explain why the Go example code works as it is?

Code in question:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func main() {
    v := Vertex{1, 2}
    p := &v
    p.X = 1e9
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In go, the compiler automatically converts the expression to `(*p).X`. From the the [language spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> if the type of x is a named pointer type and (*x).f is a valid
>   selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is
>   shorthand for (*x).f.

Comment: Thank you--this explains it.